# onSharedPreferenceChanged and variations_seed_native_stored

Tags: java, android

I started getting a weird crash on my app running on a **Moto Z2 Play Android 8.0.0** (but not on the emulator) because `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` was being triggered unexpectedly.

Upon investigation, I found that a preference "**variations_seed_native_stored**" is being changed by "someone", which is not my app (it looks like it comes from Chromium/WebView, which I do use in the app).

Is that an expected behavior? The "Shared" in "SharedPreferences" means extraneous preferences can be stored there?

If so, how would I make sure I don't have preference name conflicts, if I'm really sharing the name space?

**Specific details:**

In `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` I call a `notifyDataSetChanged()` on a RecyclerView (because settings will change how data is presented), but the unexpected "**variations_seed_native_stored**" creates a "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout" - there's a WebView in a ViewHolder, and I suppose it causes a circular calling. Following this error, there's a long Breakpad Microdump from AndroidWebView:69.0.34.97.100.

This only happens once, after the user has "reset preferences to defaults", because I do a "`prefs.edit().clear().apply()`", which removes the "**variations_seed_native_stored**", making WebView(?) write it again on the next time I update the RecyclerView, triggering the crash.

Yes, I can workaround that by doing nothing on the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` if the key = "**variations_seed_native_stored**", but then I'll be worrying with every new preference google decides to store with mine. Is it recommended that I "filter" `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` against a list of my own preferences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` are not supposed to hold many data. Create a `SharedPreference` with another name and make sure it is only used by your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid you didn't read all my post. I don't use, neither did I create the "variations_seed_native_stored", and if the namespace for the preferences is shared among other apps (one of my questions in the original post), how am I supposed to guarantee that no other app uses (or one day will use) a preference with the same name?

Comment: @jsveiga I understand your post well. You got confused about what is a name and what is a key in SharedPreferences. The "variations_seed_native_stored" is a key. Check [Context.getSharedPrefences(name, mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) for what is a name and [SharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for what is a key.

Comment: I understand that difference, but I assumed using getDefautSharedPreferences with my context, which I understand uses a unique name from the context I passed, would only be used by my app.  So may be the issue is that WebView, being in my app, uses the same context for its sharedpreferences?

Comment: @jsveiga Yes WebView uses the same context for its SharedPreferences. WebView works for multiple apps so it makes sense to store per-app configurations using SharedPreferences in each app. It surely would be better if WebView leaves the default SharedPreferences alone and use another name. But obviously we see WebView doing otherwise, and we can do nothing about it but using a different name ourselves.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use another name; what I'm doing until now is ignore the event for that particular preference.